# How to send a Rectangle object to the paint() method in Java

Tags: java, paint

I am just wondering how I can get my overridden paint() method to paint the outline of a Rectangle object. The problem is that the Rectangle object's dimension and position is arbitrary and thus the paint method cannot contain code stating how and where the Rectangle is to be drawn. So I am wondering is there a way I could somehow cast a Rectangle object to something which could be read and painted by the paint(Graphics g) method? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean with arbitrary? You will have some variables in your code containing dimensions and position of your rectangle, and each time paint is called (e.g. by repaint()) it will draw the lines.

Answer (score 4):

Rectangle implements the Shape interface and can be painted directly with a Graphics2D object -- and this is passed into the JComponent's `paintComponent` method (and also the paint method, but I don't recommend that you use this).  So you can paint a rectangle easily via

```
// in your JPanel or JComponent extended class
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponent(g);
   Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
   g2.draw(myRectangle);  // assuming that this holds the Rectangle object
   //...
}
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted. It is absolutely correct. :-) +1

Answer (score 2):

`java.awt.Graphics` has a [`drawRect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method that does just that. Its parameters match the members of a `Rectangle` object.

```
g.drawRect(r.getX(), r.getY(), r.getWidth(), r.getHeight());
```

Comment: Thank you so much mate. Your response helped a lot! Although instead of using g.drawRect as you suggested I just used g.draw(Rectangle) instead. It worked very well and now I can see why my collision detection was not working. The rectangles are all over the place. Thanks again mate. Have a good one.

Answer (score 2):

Your class needs to be able to request the rectangle from somewhere else in your code.

```
public interface RectangleProvider {
 Rectangle getRectangle();
}

public MyPanel extendeds JPAnel {
  private final RectangleProvider _provider;
  public MyPanel(RectangleProvider provider) {
    _provider = provider;
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Rectangle r = _provider.getRectangle();
    // ...
  }
}
```

This way, you have your code that determines what the shape is. Then, as needed, the component can get acccess to it and base its painting operations.

Comment: Thanks for your response mate. I used your advice in conjunction with that of Mat (below) and was able to paint my Rectangles and ultimately realize why my collision detection was not working. Thank you very much for your reply, couldn't have done it without you. Have a good one mate.

Comment: @DillonChaffey: Please up-vote any answer that helped you, and "accept" the single best answer.